# Technical implementation of tracking frequency of Chrome extension use

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to implement some new features for "heavy" users of my Google Chrome extension - such as limiting the amount of results they are served - as a means of encouraging users to sign up to a premium plan. I'm aware of other chrome extensions that perform this kind of functionality, but am unaware of how to go about implementing this.

I'm wondering can I use something like Cookies or session storage but nothing obvious comes to mind. Can anyone suggest/ share a starting point or even if the idea is viable.